# Getting 401 unauthorized error in /requests endpoint of Uber API

Tags: uber-api

I have tried using the /requests endpoint with my Uber developer account's owner and developer accounts, but I get this error: 
401 unauthorized, 
{ 
"message": "This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: request.delegate.tos_accept, request, request.delegate", "code": "unauthorized" 
}

My HTTP call is as follows:

POST https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/requests

Headers:

Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_MY_DEVELOPER_ACCOUNT
Accept-Language: en_US
Content-Type: application/json

Parameters:
{"start_latitude":"21.1741125","start_longitude":"72.8121804","end_latitude":"21.2048986","end_longitude":"72.8386455"}

Whereas I get proper response from /requests/estimate endpoint with the same access token, for the same location parameters.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have not requested the 'request' scope during the [oauth authorization process](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#authorize).

Comment: But I think the same request scope is required for the /requests/estimate endpoint too and thats working fine. However it is written in the documentation of Uber API that privileged scopes like request are already available with the developer account or owner account's access token. I am using the access token generated from developer dashboard.

Comment: Yes, the token in the dashboard does not include the 'request' scope since it is not a default scope. You should authorize a new token and pass in the 'request' scope and it will work as intended.

Comment: Hi, I've tried the authorization procedure marked in the documentation. It redirects me to the Uber login page, but unfortunately after entering my credentials, it gives me the following error: 

UBER, 

Error

Unknown application


. URL is like this: https://login.uber.com/oauth/errors?error=invalid_client_id#_.

I've checked my client id, but that is correct

Comment: It looks like the credentials are incorrect or there is a typo in the parameter names.

Comment: Hi, I've finally managed it. My problem was that I had created a form for redirecting to the login.uber.com, due to which I was getting the unknown aplication error. I have now converted it to <a> tag and it works like a charm. @dustin Thank you so much for your help and patience to bear with me.